# reducing tps in kafka disks on linux

Tags: linux, kafka, sar

we're using kafka brokers with:

- 24 HT cores
- 256GB RAM
- 16 X 7.2K RPM NLSAS disks configured in RAID-10 and replication
  factor 3.

the sar -q
command the runq-sz reached ~40 on average, load average reached 10 and the CPU was only 10% us and 5% sys.

that didn't explain the high value of runq-sz, so we ran sar -d and saw following:

- the tps of the device is ~650
- %util is ~30%
- rd_sec is ~60K
- wr_sec is ~200K.
- there's a linear correlation between the tps and the %util.

I've got two questions:

1) Is there a way of decreasing the tps?

2) if there's such a way - will it decrease the %util?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I try to reduce the %util because the amount of data written to the kafka will increase and I don't want to add more disks.

Comment: That is not a problem description, that is a metric. Storage systems exist that run near 100% utilized with adequate response times. Why do you think you exceed the IOPS capacity of your 16 spindles? What is the read/write distribution and size of your I/Os? What I/O response time do you require?